# django 1.9 models_module missing in migration apps

Tags: django, migration, django-migrations

I'm migrating from django 1.8 to django 1.9.

I have a migration that adds a group `user` and then a permission `django_comments.add_comment` to that group. The migration that works with django 1.8 looks like this

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_contenttypes
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions


def create_perms(apps, schema_editor):
  update_contenttypes(apps.get_app_config('django_comments'))
  create_permissions(apps.get_app_config('django_comments'))

  Group = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')
  group = Group(name='user')
  group.save()

  commentct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(apps.get_model('django_comments', 'comment'))

  group.permissions.add([Permission.objects.get(codename='add_comment', content_type_id=commentct)])
  group.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name'),
        ('django_comments', '0002_update_user_email_field_length')
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_perms, remove_perms)
    ]
```

When upgrading to django 1.9, this throws an error because the contenttype  cannot be found. This is because when `update_contenttypes` call is not creating the necessary content_types. There is this line inside that function ([django's source code reference](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/contenttypes/management.py#L12))

```
def update_contenttypes(app_config, verbosity=2, interactive=True, using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, **kwargs):
    if not app_config.models_module:
         return
    ...
```

This `app_config.models_module` is `None` in django 1.9, but is **not** `None` in django 1.8

If I replace that for this code

```
def update_contenttypes(app_config, verbosity=2, interactive=True, using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, **kwargs):
    if not app_config.models_module:
         #return
         pass
    ...
```

Then all works ok.

The thing is I don't want to change django's core code. How can I make this work in django 1.9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, thanks to some help in #django IRC (user knbk), I found an ugly workaround but at least it works!

Change this two lines

```
  update_contenttypes(apps.get_app_config('django_comments'))
  create_permissions(apps.get_app_config('django_comments'))
```

Write this instead

```
  app = apps.get_app_config('django_comments')
  app.models_module = app.models_module or True
  update_contenttypes(app)
  create_permissions(app)
```

Now it works just fine.

Comment: Using Django 1.11 update_contenttypes no longer exists, use create_contenttypes instead